# C++ raises error: use of undeclared identifier c++ on calling constructor from header file

Tags: c++

I keep getting the `cpp/ItemsToPurchase.cpp:8:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'name' this->itemName=name;` on the following code. There are three files; `ItemToPurchase.h`, `ItemToPurchase.cpp` and `main.cpp`.

Any help would be appreciated.

`ItemToPurchase.h`

```
#ifndef ITEMTOPURCHASE_H
#define ITEMTOPURCHASE_H
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class ItemToPurchase
{
public:
    ItemToPurchase();

    void setItemName(string name);
    void setItemPrice(int itemPrice);
    void setItemQuantity(int itemQuantity);

    string getItemName();
    int getItemPrice();
    int getItemQuantity();

    virtual ~ItemToPurchase();
protected:
private:
    string itemName ;
    int itemPrice;
    int itemQuantity ;
};
#endif // ITEMTOPURCHASE_H
```

`ItemToPurchase.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ItemToPurchase.h"
ItemToPurchase::ItemToPurchase()
{
    this->itemName="none";
    this->itemPrice=0;
    this->itemQuantity=0;
    this->itemName=name;
}

void ItemToPurchase::setItemPrice(int itemPrice)
{
    this->itemPrice=itemPrice;
}

void ItemToPurchase::setItemQuantity(int itemQuantity)
{
    this->itemQuantity=itemQuantity;
}

string ItemToPurchase::getItemName()
{
    return itemName;
}

int ItemToPurchase::getItemPrice()
{
    return itemPrice;
}

int ItemToPurchase::getItemQuantity()
{
    return itemQuantity;
}

ItemToPurchase::~ItemToPurchase()
{
    //dtor
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ItemToPurchase.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ItemToPurchase item1,item2;
    string itemName ;
    int itemPrice;
    int itemQuantity ;
    int totalCost=0;

    cout << "Item 1:" << endl;
    cout << "Enter the item name : ";
    getline(cin,itemName);
    //cin.ignore();

    cout << "Enter the item price : ";
    cin >> itemPrice;

    cout << "Enter the item quantity : ";
    cin >> itemQuantity;

    item1.setItemName(itemName);
    item1.setItemPrice(itemPrice);
    item1.setItemQuantity(itemQuantity);
    cin.ignore();

    cout << "Item 2:" << endl;
    cout << "Enter the item name : ";
    getline(cin,itemName);
    //cin.ignore();
    
    cout<<"Enter the item price : ";
    cin>>itemPrice;

    cout<<"Enter the item quantity : ";
    cin>>itemQuantity;

    item2.setItemName(itemName);
    item2.setItemPrice(itemPrice);
    item2.setItemQuantity(itemQuantity);

    cout << "TOTAL COST : " << endl;
    cout << item1.getItemName() << " " << item1.getItemQuantity() << " @ $"
        << item1.getItemPrice() << " = " <<
        (item1.getItemQuantity()*item1.getItemPrice()) << endl;
    cout << item2.getItemName() << " " << item2.getItemQuantity() << " @ $"
        << item2.getItemPrice() << " = " <<
        (item2.getItemQuantity()*item2.getItemPrice()) << endl;
    totalCost = (item1.getItemQuantity()*item1.getItemPrice()) + (item2.getItemQuantity()*item2.getItemPrice());
    cout << "Total : $" << totalCost << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as the error message tells: There is no symbol `name` in the scope of the `ItemToPurchase` construcor.

```
ItemToPurchase::ItemToPurchase()
{
this->itemName="none"; // here you set name to "none"
this->itemPrice=0;
this->itemQuantity=0;
this->itemName=name;  // here you try to set the name again
}
```

In `main()` you call a method `setItemName` which is not implemented as far I can tell it is only declared in the header file. I assume you tried to do something like:

```
ItemToPurchase::ItemToPurchase()
{
this->itemName="none"; // here you set the name to "none"
this->itemPrice=0;
this->itemQuantity=0;
}

ItemToPurchase::setItemName(std::string name)
{
this->itemName=name;   // here you set the actual name
}
```

Comment: Hello @ccdMuro. Thank you for your suggestions and I have made the changes by calling the method in the ItemTo Purchase.cpp but to no avail. I am still getting the same error? In your opinion, could it be something more?

Comment: If you remove the line `this->itemName=name;` from the constructor, you should at least get an other message. Please confirm that you removed this line.

Answer (score 0):

The only place an identifier `name` is declared in the source code you show is as a parameter of `setItemName` in `ItemToPurchase.h`. At the place where the error occurs, line 8 in `ItemToPurchase.cpp`, it is in the routine `ItemToPurchase`, and no declaration of `name` is in scope.

That explains the error message. As for correcting it, what do you expect `this->itemName=name;` to do? It has to know what `name` is so it can get its value. What `name` do you expect it to use? Or maybe you want to initialize `itemName` to an empty string or some default name like “unnamed item”?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am however a beginner in this. How would I go about it?  I have tried to initialize ```name``` in the ItemToPurchase.cpp as "none" but I still get the same error. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: In fact earlier in the default constructor `itemName` _is_ initialized to a default name, `"none"`. So just dropping the line `this->itemName=name;` from the default constructor entirely seems fine.

Comment: Hello Nathan, the error has changed to error: linker command failed with exit code 1, any thoughts on where it could be coming from?

Comment: Did you add a definition for `ItemToPurchase::setItemName`?

Comment: yes. Please confirm if its correct ``` void ItemToPurchase::setItemName(string name)
{
this->itemName=name;   // here you set the actual name
}```

Comment: What exactly is the error you are currently getting?